# Copying JP2000 from Mosiac Dataset turns white

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, jpeg-2000

I am trying to copy a raster to jp2000 from another File Geodatabase that I created as a Mosaic Dataset.

It came out as a whiteout in the middle. I don't know what it cause this.

See screenshot :  Mosiac Dataset : [image: Mosaic Dataset]

See Post copied from Mosiac Dataset to the new File Geodatase : [image: Post Jp2000]
See Result log : [image]

Why does this jp2000 cause it to turn white?

Comment: This looks like a job for ESRI support.

Comment: do you have "normal" values when you click in the white area ?

Comment: How do I do that ? radouxju

Comment: with the "identify" tool (blue disk with an "i") in the toolbar with zoom tools

Comment: Awww...ok..I checked and it says "No Data" - radouxju

Comment: I noticed on your result log that the pixel type is not identified. Are there different pixel types for the different images ?

Comment: Ok where do I find that on the log so I can go back and check. Also, it is not on my computer so it is on another computer.

Comment: radouxju - I found the pixel type and gave it blank. I checked the information from the original and it shows me the Pixel Type :unsigned integer and the pixel depth: is 8 bit.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to import from a mosaic dataset into a jpg2000 raster. Can you try using the source files of the mosaic directly?

Comment: Dowlers -- yes using the Copy Raster toolbox. If you right click export with ArcMap that woudld not work.

Comment: If anyone in here has a no clue as to why this occurred , I will have to get a ticket to ESRI to find out the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever follow up with ESRI about this?

Comment: No, not yet. blah238

Answer (score 1):

Well, this look like a bug. So here is a workaround.

1. install GDAL (e.g. using [OSGEO4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/))
2. create a vrt with all your files (using [gdalbuildvrt](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html))
3. translate your vrt into jp2000 (using [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html))

Comment: I might try re-do and force the pixel type to uninterger signed and 8 bit.

Comment: I would try with a larger pixel depth.

Comment: Radouxju -what type of pixels and number do you think should I try with ?

Comment: For JP2000, it has to be unsigned integer. If it doesn't work with 8 bit, I would try it with 16 bit. 16_BIT_UNSIGNED

Comment: Radouxju - Ok. Wish me a luck ! If I get it right.

Answer (score 0):

I re-tried and this time with a larger pixel type and 16 bit unsigned. It failed this time and I am suspecting that our computers may have missing some critical files that needed to run properly. I just found out that our ERDAS 2013 has some problems and my ArcGIS 10.1 missed some important files to fun some tools.

We are under US Government so they have to test the software to be certified before they can be install. So if there are some files such .NET framework or MSXML or any other important files that needed to be install. They can get screwed up easily. So that is what I am suspecting and I have already report to have it fixed.